# No content using $getjson

Tags: json, each, getjson

Hope some of you can help me. I am new into this json/jquery thing.

I have some problems with rendering a array using getjson.

My json output is:

```
{"item":[{"id":"24","utoken":"e43aa84cc304a1ed3722832616294516b118a5c2","st_type":"2","st_action":"cvb","st_situation":"cvbc"},{"id":"25","utoken":"e43aa84cc304a1ed3722832616294516b118a5c2","st_type":"1","st_action":"vbnv","st_situation":"vbnv"}]}
```

And my javascript is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON('showastrategy.php?utoken=<? echo $_SESSION['utoken']; ?>', 

function(data){
strategylist = data.items;
$.each(strategylist, function(index, strategy) {
    $('#altcontent').append('<li>' + strategy.id + '' +
    '<p>' +  strategy.utoken + ' ' +  strategy.st_title + '</p>' +
    '<p>' +  strategy.st_action + '</p>' +
    '' +  strategy.st_situation + '</li>');

    });
 });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all; `data.items` doesn't exist.

use:

```
function(data) {
    for(var i in data['item']) {
        $('#altcontent').append('<li>' + data['item'][i].id + '' +
        '<p>' +  data['item'][i].utoken + ' ' +  data['item'][i].st_title + '</p>' +
        '<p>' +  data['item'][i].st_action + '</p>' +
        '' +  data['item'][i].st_situation + '</li>');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't upvote your answer, but it is accepted now. Sorry and thank you again :)